# Cisco ASA allow no-nat public subnets

Tags: cisco-asa, nat, arin

Testing in a lab...I have a VLAN directly attached to a **Cisco ASA 5520** that contains host machines who use IPs from a public address space,  **11.11.11.0/26** for example. The ASA has two interfaces this dmz interface containing the hosts on the **11.11.11.0/26** and an outside interface containing a /30 peering point to an ASR running BGP etc.

Is there a way to configure the ASA to allow connectivity to and from this 11.11.11.0/26 without having to put in NAT statements since both interfaces are two different security-levels?

- **dmz security-level 50 (11.11.11.1/26)**
- **outside security-level 0 (11.11.11.65/30) to ASR**

Thanks for everyones help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable nat-control. Apply permit acl to outside interface.

Comment: Hmm,  the command errors as it is depreciated, I am running 8.4.2

Comment: After 8.3 there is no nat-control. So you should configure nat exemption. Here is how you can achieve that: object network LOCAL_LAN
subnet 11.11.11.0 255.255.255.192
object network REMOTE_LAN
subnet 11.11.11.64 255.255.255.252
nat (dmz,outside) source static LOCAL_LAN LOCAL_LAN destination static REMOTE_LAN REMOTE_LAN

Comment: Thank Nuran, that is as far as I got however I can't specify "any" as the REMOTE_LAN?? for example what if it is 11.11.11.11 to 8.8.8.8, how do I ensure no nat control is happening?

Comment: So apparently i didn't assign my outside ACL to my outside interface via access-group command. I figured it out when I did a packet-tracer and it kept saying it was denied by ACL. Thanks for your help.